# Regex (JS) read data between two symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

My changelog.md data looks like below.

```
## 11.2.3
* xxx
* xxxx

## 11.2.2
* ttt
* ttt
```

I need a regex that can return only the first versions list ie.

```
* xxx
* xxxx
```

I tried multiple solutions but, didn't reach the final result.

I tried matching, and replacing it, didn't work.

```js
const changelog = `
## Hello World
* This is a bold text
* This is a bold text

## Hello World
* This is a bold text

## Hello World
* This is a bold text
`;

const final = changelog.match( /([^(##)])(.*)[^(##)]/g );
console.log(final);
```

Comment: Show what you tried, we'll help you fix it. We won't write it for scratch for you.

Comment: If you use `.*`, remember that you have to use the `s` flag to allow this to match across multiple lines.

Comment: const changelog = `
## Hello World
* This is a bold text
* This is a bold text

## Hello Worl
* This is a bold text

## Hello World
* This is a bold text
`;

const final = msg.match( /([^(##)])(.*)[^(##)]/g );

Comment: Put the code in the question so you can format it properly. Use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I need the first match so I removed "g" and used "m" for multiline but with first match only. This is fine but final result is not expected.

Comment: `[^(##)]` doesn't mean whatever you think it means.

Comment: I realized, it is actually doing the reverse.

Comment: `[^abc]` matches a character that isn't `a`, `b`, or `c`. So `[^(##)]` matches a character that isn't `(` or `#`. You seem to think that `[]` is for grouping.

Comment: Ok, make sense, then how to check the - starts with and ends with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put `^##` inside `[]`. Square brackets are for making character sets, `()` is for grouping. There's no need to group it if you're not interested in that part.

Use the `m` modifier to make `^` match the beginning of a line instead of the the beginning of the string. Then `.*\n` will match the rest of that line. `[^#]*` will match everything after that until the next `#`.

```js
const changelog = `
## Hello World
* This is a bold text
* This is a bold text

## Hello World
* This is a bold text

## Hello World
* This is a bold text
`;

const final = changelog.match(/^##.*\n([^#]*)/m);
console.log(final[1]);
```

Comment: This worked, how do you know this? Can you guide me on where I read about regex?

Comment: www.regular-expression.info

Comment: @Barmar: Small clarification: "There's no need to group it if you're not interested in that part." In fact you CAN'T make a group inside a character class.

Comment: @PoulBak I know that, but he was using `[]` for grouping, not making a class.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. If you do `console.log(changelog)` before applying the regex, does it contain the expected value?

Comment: Yes, that's a different problem, sorry asked here. Yes, actually it gives the right result on a fixed string (like asked above), I might need to store it in a const or make it a string, because the whole change log file is quite big, so may be it is not able to do it so quickly.